# Retrieve jQuery requested ajax URL and compare if matches

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to grab the requested AJAX URL generated by a plugin to use in my callback. My intention is, to say in plain English: If the current requested AJAX URL matches attribute href in a certain selector already available in the page, then do something.

```
  $(selector).myplugin({settings},function(){
    if (currentAjaxURL == $(another selector).attr('href') ) {
      // do something
    }
  });
```

Is there any way for jQuery to get currentAjaxURL via the active current requested URL? 
Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to intercept ajax calls? Observe them as they flow past?

Comment: If possible yes. I am looking for the last call to compare actually, but no way to know that either. So I thought comparing the current request to the existing element will do what I need. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [global ajax events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) in the jquery docs, you can listen for requests being sent (before they send, when they start, when they complete etc...) and get the XMLHttpRequest object directly, then you could compare the URL to the dom element's href attribute.